# How can I install GCC runtime libraries with CMake?

Tags: gcc, cmake, mingw

I've compiled a C++ program and it's perfectly working on my computer, but if my friend tries to launch the program, it says `libgcc_s_sw2-1.dll` is missing. How I can include all the required GCC runtime libraries with the program using CMake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As rubenvb correctly answers: libgcc is required or you should add `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-static` to your CMakeLists.txt.

As an alternative, you could try to find libgcc_s_sw2-1.dll in your MinGW installation and "package" it with your installation using [InstallRequiredSystemLibraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module:InstallRequiredSystemLibraries). This integrates nicely with [CPack](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cpack.html) as well.

E.g. in my own code, I have:

```
if( MINGW )
    message( STATUS "    Installing system-libraries: MinGW DLLs." )
    get_filename_component( Mingw_Path ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} PATH )
    set( CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS ${Mingw_Path}/mingwm10.dll ${Mingw_Path}/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll ${Mingw_Path}/libstdc++-6.dll )
endif( MINGW )
include( InstallRequiredSystemLibraries )
```

Later on, in the part which prepares an install or package:

```
# Actually install it when make install is called.
# Note, this works with CPack
if( CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS )
    install( PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS} DESTINATION bin COMPONENT System )
endif( CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS )
```

Comment: note that MinGW-w64 doesn't have `mingwm10.dll`, and they generally provide `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`, and GCC 4.8 for x64 will have a `libgcc_s_seh-0.dll` by default. The automatic packaging of libgcc is very build system dependent.

Comment: @rubenvb. True and I think your solution is the better one. But in those cases where a user does want to build against libgcc as a dll, at least with CMake it is possible to collect all those system dependent files. In my own project, I have even written a little script which does this for MinGW, VS2008 and VS2010.

Answer (score 5):

The libgcc dll is required by all programs compiled with GCC. If you don't want to redistribute this DLL with your program, you must link statically by passing `-static` to the linker, or in CMake:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-static
```

This is specific for GCC.